# Firebase - How many times in a day "Firebase InApp Campaigns are fetched from service"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have implemented **Firebase InApp Messaging** & have few questions regarding the same. Once we launch the app got this message in logcat "Fetching campaigns from service."

1. How many times in a day firebase fetches the campaigns from service.(I am not talking about the per device frequency)
2. Is there any time interval for the above?

I have gone through the firebase docs but there is nothing mentioned like this. Also referred the below blog for the latency from app to firebase console.(but there is nothing mentioned about the InApp messaging)

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html

**Assumptions:**

Based on my findings, I came to know that "Firebase InApp messaging" is to send the contextual messages to valuable users. So firebase **don't want to spam the messages** to users.(may fetches campaigns only once in a day once app launch)

Please if anyone have idea about the same share your finding as well.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a feature request open to improve this. Please give it a thumbs up if you think it's worth it: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3979

Answer (score 5):

Per this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=android#send_a_test_message), Firebase In-App Messaging only retrieves messages from the server once per day. The exact interval time isn't directly specified, however it should fetch new messages when the date changes.