# New published Firebase InApp message campaigns( with custom trigger event) are visible only after fresh install of App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-console, firebase-in-app-messaging

I am trying to use firebase in-app messaging for different screen events( different activities with custom trigger events in OnCreate()).

The problem I am facing:
Suppose There are some already published in-app campaigns (with custom trigger events)in the firebase console before the installation of the App's APK.

After the fresh installation with APK, the app shows already published campaigns well.

Now I publish some new campaign(with some different screen custom event trigger), and after publishing this new campaign I reopen my app and visit that screen(screen with the custom trigger of newly published campaign), the newly published campaign is not visible (expected behavior it should be visible).

If I reinstall my app again, all published campaigns are visible(along with the latest published campaign).

I don't want to reinstall the app every time for new campaigns.

Please help me if you have any information about this. Thank you so much!

reference :

```
https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/modify-message-behavior?platform=android#trigger_in-app_messages_programmatically_2
```

code snippets I followed:

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().triggerEvent("activityD"); ( using this code line in OnCreate() and OnResume() in my Activity. publishing campaign with the same trigger string.
```

code snippets I also experimented with:

```
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setMessagesSuppressed(false);
FirebaseInAppMessaging.getInstance().setAutomaticDataCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Expectations: I placed different trigger events on different screens. After that, I publish a in-app campaign with a custom trigger. The user should receive the message just after it visits that screen with the custom trigger event. There should be no need for a fresh installation of the App.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62639847/20447561).

In-App Messaging will only fetch campaigns [once per day](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=android#send_a_test_message:%7E:text=Firebase%20In%2DApp%20Messaging%20only%20retrieves%20messages%20from%20the%20server%20once%20per%20day). The app fetched all active campaigns when you installed it. That's why the published campaign after that is not included. It'll be fetched until the next cycle. Afaik, there's no workaround for this. You can use "Test on Device" just to make sure that the campaign is working. Then, just wait for it to be fetched in the next cycle.